# Using a C library with Swift (multi pointers and all)

Tags: c, xcode, swift, pointers, memory

I have a C function that I am trying to access from Swift. The prototype is:

```
short qed(struct sur *sur, float up, float vp, float j, short pfl,
                  struct vector ***Q, float **u, float **v, int *k, int *l,
                  struct stack *S)
```

So I get how to pass things into the C functions from swift, until we get to pointers. The main pointers I am struggling with are the u, v, and Q. In C, I would do it like this:

```
float *u, *v;
struct vector **Q;
qed(doc.sur[0], 0.1, 0.1, 0.75, 1, &Q, &u, &v, &k, &l, &S);
//Where doc.sur is a struct sur pointer and the memory allocation is done in the function.
```

How would I do this in swift? I know I need some combination of UnsafeMutablePointer. struct vector ***Q, float **u, float **v are input and used for output.

UPDATE
Here is the declaration of vector:

```
struct vector {
    float  x, y, z;             /* Vector coordinates */
};
```

The vector for the function is essentially a 2D array of points in 3D space.

Comment: I added an answer for u and v. Please include the C declaration of vector if you need help with that one.

Comment: Ok, I have added the declaration of the struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a C function like this:

```
void f(float **u, float **v, struct vector ***Q);
```

You can call it from Swift like this:

```
var u = UnsafeMutablePointer<CFloat>()
var v = UnsafeMutablePointer<CFloat>()
var Q = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<vector>>()

f(&u, &v, &Q)

print(u.memory)
print(v.memory)
print(Q.memory[0])
```